# Mongoose update array of Object id's using Populate?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to populate my array of an object id's how can i do ??

**Function**

```
$scope.assignEmployees = function () {
var chkArray = [];
var companyName = $scope.selectedComapny.companyName;
var Indata = {chkvalue:chkArray,company_name:companyName};
$("#employee_name:checked").each(function() {
        chkArray.push($(this).val());
    });
$http({
    method  : 'PUT',
    url     : '/api/projects',
    data    : Indata
})
.success(function (data){
    console.log(data);
});}
```

**Mongoose api**

**Population code:-**

```
   Project.findOne({client : company_name})
   .populate('assignedTo')
   .exec(function(err, project) {
        if (err) return;

        while(i<employee_id.length){
            project.assignedTo.push(employee_id[i]);
            project.save(function(err) {

                if (err) return;


            })
            i++;
         }

      });
```

This code is work but it insert value 4 times any idea guys.

Comment: You can try something like `Project.updateOne({client : company_name},{"$push":{"assignedTo":{"$each":employee_id }}, function(err, data){if (err) return;});`

Comment: Dude its not working

Comment: Please checked my population code

Comment: Sorry I've missed the closing parenthesis. Try `Project.updateOne({client : company_name},{"$push":{"assignedTo":{"$each":employee_id }}}, function(err, data){if (err) return;})`;

Comment: Dude i try your solution its not working.. can you check the updated question..??

Comment: You should move the `save` logic out of `while` loop. First add the values into the array and then save.

Comment: yes wait i will try..

Comment: Btw you should use `updateOne` and it should work as expected. Please show me  the update query that you have.

Comment: Its done Dude... :)

Comment: I used this query  `Project.findOneAndUpdate({client : company_name},{"$push":{"assignedTo":{"$each":employee_id }}}, function(err, data){if (err) return;});`

Comment: And this one didn't work for you ?

Comment: Yes the value not getting updated..

Comment: Can you please show your schema?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to push all elements of Array to an Array in mongoose.

```
Project.update(
   { client: company_name },
   { "$pushAll": { "assignedTo": employee_id } },
   function (err, raw) {
      if (err) return handleError(err);
      console.log('The raw response from Mongo was ', raw);
   }
);
```